Are questions about where to get some specific types of samples on-topic in Music P&T SE?
I was wondering if recommendations questions about where to get some specific types of samples are on-topic here. Usually these types of questions are forbidden in other SE communities. But this question (Guitar digital samples library) made me think may be they are allowed here, since the reason it was closed says he's asking for a specific product recommendation, and not because is a question about where to get a specific type of sample.
Specifically, I would like to ask about where to get free to use ambient sounds and fillers.

Our Help Centre article What topics can I ask about here? says that questions about…

shopping help — including product or music search — or buying/selling advice or recommendations

… are not on-topic.
The question you link to and the question you want to ask (both about where to get samples) are shopping help type questions.  So they aren’t on-topic here.  Sorry.
